# Display a certain element in a list

Tags: python, list, selection

Right now our code creates a grid starting at the top left and filling in rows and columns from left to right, row by row.  Currently, there are a bunch of images it can pick from.  It is set using a handful of IF statements that picks between shapes and rareshapes.  What I am trying to figure out how to do is change the code so instead of it picking a random rareshape, I can decide what rareshape spawns.  Still new to Python and finding a lot of little things that make sense to me from other languages don't work in Python so its throwing me off a little.

EDIT:

Here is the full code.  Credit for the base code written by cactusbin and revised by Gareth Rees.

```
import pygame, random, time, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import itertools
import os

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

SHAPE_WIDTH = 64                # Width of each shape (pixels).
SHAPE_HEIGHT = 64               # Height of each shape (pixels).
PUZZLE_COLUMNS = 10              # Number of columns on the board.
PUZZLE_ROWS = 11                # Number of rows on the board.
MARGIN = 118                     # Margin around the board (pixels).
WINDOW_WIDTH = PUZZLE_COLUMNS * SHAPE_WIDTH + 2 * MARGIN + 485
WINDOW_HEIGHT = PUZZLE_ROWS * SHAPE_HEIGHT + 2 * MARGIN - 150
FONT_SIZE = 60
TEXT_OFFSET = MARGIN + 950

# Map from number of matches to points scored.
MINIMUM_MATCH = 10
EXTRA_LENGTH_POINTS = .1
RANDOM_POINTS = .3
DELAY_PENALTY_SECONDS = 1
DELAY_PENALTY_POINTS = 0

FPS = 30
EXPLOSION_SPEED = 15            # In frames per second.
SPIN_SPEED = 15
REFILL_SPEED = 10               # In cells per second.

VERTICAL = False

class Cell(object):
"""
A cell on the board, with properties:
`image` -- a `Surface` object containing the sprite to draw here.
`offset` -- vertical offset in pixels for drawing this cell.
"""
def __init__(self, image):
    self.offset = 0.0
    self.image = image

def tick(self, dt):
    self.offset = max(0.0, self.offset - dt * REFILL_SPEED)

class Board(object):
"""
A rectangular board of cells, with properties:
`w` -- width in cells.
`h` -- height in cells.
`size` -- total number of cells.
`board` -- list of cells.
`matches` -- list of matches, each being a list of exploding cells.
`refill` -- list of cells that are moving up to refill the board.
`score` -- score due to chain reactions.
"""
def __init__(self, width, height):
    self.explosion = [pygame.image.load('images/explosion{}.png'.format(i))
                      for i in range(1, 7)]
    self.spin = [pygame.image.load('images/powerframe{}.png'.format(i))
                  for i in range (1, 12)]
    self.image_color = {}
    self.shapes = []
    self.rareshapes = []

    colors = 'red blue yellow'
    letters = 'acgtu'

    for c in colors.split():
        im = pygame.image.load('images/{}.png'.format(c))
        self.shapes.append(im)
        self.image_color[im] = c
        for l in letters:
            im = pygame.image.load('rareimages/{}{}.png'.format(c, l))
            self.rareshapes.append(im)
            self.image_color[im] = l

    self.background = pygame.image.load("images/bg.png")
    self.blank = pygame.image.load("images/blank.png")
    self.x = pygame.image.load("images/x.png")
    self.w = width
    self.h = height
    self.size = width * height
    self.board = [Cell(self.blank) for _ in range(self.size)]
    self.matches = []
    self.refill = []
    self.score = 0.0
    self.spin_time = 15


def randomize(self):
    """
    Replace the entire board with fresh shapes.
    """
    rare_shapes = [1, 9, 23, 27, 40, 42, 50, 56, 70, 81, 90]

    for i in range(self.size):
        if i in rare_shapes:
            self.board[i] = Cell(random.choice(self.rareshapes))
        else:
            self.board[i] = Cell(random.choice(self.shapes))

def pos(self, i, j):
    """
    Return the index of the cell at position (i, j).
    """
    assert(0 <= i < self.w)
    assert(0 <= j < self.h)
    return j * self.w + i

def busy(self):
    """
    Return `True` if the board is busy animating an explosion or a
    refill and so no further swaps should be permitted.
    """
    return self.refill or self.matches

def tick(self, dt):
    """
    Advance the board by `dt` seconds: move rising blocks (if
    any); otherwise animate explosions for the matches (if any);
    otherwise check for matches.
    """
    if self.refill:
        for c in self.refill:
            c.tick(dt)
        self.refill = [c for c in self.refill if c.offset > 0]
        if self.refill:
            return
    elif self.matches:
        self.explosion_time += dt
        f = int(self.explosion_time * EXPLOSION_SPEED)
        if f < len(self.explosion):
            self.update_matches(self.explosion[f])
            return
        self.update_matches(self.blank)
        self.refill = list(self.refill_columns())
    self.explosion_time = 0
    self.matches = self.find_matches()

def draw(self, display):
    """
    Draw the board on the pygame surface `display`.
    """
    display.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
    for i, c in enumerate(self.board):
        display.blit(c.image,
                     (MARGIN + SHAPE_WIDTH * (i % self.w),
                      MARGIN + SHAPE_HEIGHT * (i // self.w - c.offset) - 68))
    display.blit(self.x, (995, 735))
    display.blit(self.x, (1112, 735))
    display.blit(self.x, (1228, 735))

def swap(self, cursor):
    """
    Swap the two board cells covered by `cursor` and update the
    matches.
    """
    i = self.pos(*cursor)
    b = self.board
    b[i], b[i+1] = b[i+1], b[i]
    self.matches = self.find_matches()


def find_matches(self):
    """
    Search for matches (lines of cells with identical images) and
    return a list of them, each match being represented as a list
    of board positions.
    """
    def lines():
        for j in range(self.h):
            yield range(j * self.w, (j + 1) * self.w)
        for i in range(self.w):
            yield range(i, self.size, self.w)
    def key(i):
        return self.image_color.get(self.board[i].image)
    def matches():
        for line in lines():
            for _, group in itertools.groupby(line, key):
                match = list(group)
                if len(match) >= MINIMUM_MATCH:
                    yield match
                    self.score = self.score + 1
    return list(matches())

def update_matches(self, image):
    """
    Replace all the cells in any of the matches with `image`.
    """
    for match in self.matches:
        for position in match:
            self.board[position].image = image

def refill_columns(self):
    """
    Move cells downwards in columns to fill blank cells, and
    create new cells as necessary so that each column is full. Set
    appropriate offsets for the cells to animate into place.
    """
    for i in range(self.w):
        target = self.size - i - 1
        for pos in range(target, -1, -self.w):
            if self.board[pos].image != self.blank:
                c = self.board[target]
                c.image = self.board[pos].image
                c.offset = (target - pos) // self.w
                target -= self.w
                yield c
        offset = 1 + (target - pos) // self.w
        for pos in range(target, -1, -self.w):
            c = self.board[pos]
            c.image = random.choice(self.shapes)
            c.offset = offset
            yield c

class Game(object):
"""
The state of the game, with properties:
`clock` -- the pygame clock.
`display` -- the window to draw into.
`font` -- a font for drawing the score.
`board` -- the board of cells.
`cursor` -- the current position of the (left half of) the cursor.
`score` -- the player's score.
`last_swap_ticks` -- 
`swap_time` -- time since last swap (in seconds).
"""
def __init__(self):
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Nucleotide")
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT),
                                           DOUBLEBUF)
    self.board = Board(PUZZLE_COLUMNS, PUZZLE_ROWS)
    self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, FONT_SIZE)

def start(self):
    """
    Start a new game with a random board.
    """
    self.board.randomize()
    self.cursor = [0, 0]
    self.score = 0.0
    self.swap_time = 125

def quit(self):
    """
    Quit the game and exit the program.
    """
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def play(self):
    """
    Play a game: repeatedly tick, draw and respond to input until
    the QUIT event is received.
    """
    self.start()
    while True:
        self.draw()
        dt = min(self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000, 1 / FPS)
        self.swap_time -= dt
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYUP:
                self.input(event.key)
            elif event.type == QUIT:
                self.quit()
            elif self.swap_time == 0:
                self.quit()
        self.board.tick(dt)

def input(self, key):
    """
    Respond to the player pressing `key`.
    """
    if key == K_q:
        self.quit()
    elif key == K_RIGHT and self.cursor[0] < self.board.w - 2:
        self.cursor[0] += 1
    elif key == K_LEFT and self.cursor[0] > 0:
        self.cursor[0] -= 1
    elif key == K_DOWN and self.cursor[1] < self.board.h - 1:
        self.cursor[1] += 1
    elif key == K_UP and self.cursor[1] > 0:
        self.cursor[1] -= 1
    elif key == K_SPACE and not self.board.busy():
        self.swap()

def swap(self):
    """
    Swap the two cells under the cursor and update the player's score.
    """
    self.board.swap(self.cursor)

def draw(self):
    self.board.draw(self.display)
    self.draw_score()
    self.draw_time()
    if VERTICAL == False:
        self.draw_cursor()
    elif VERTICAL == True:
        self.draw_cursor2()
    pygame.display.update()

def draw_time(self):
    s = int(self.swap_time)
    text = self.font.render(str(int(s/60)) + ":" + str(s%60).zfill(2),
                            True, BLACK)
    self.display.blit(text, (TEXT_OFFSET, WINDOW_HEIGHT - 170))

def draw_score(self):
    total_score = self.score

def draw_cursor(self):
    topLeft = (MARGIN + self.cursor[0] * SHAPE_WIDTH,
            MARGIN + self.cursor[1] * SHAPE_HEIGHT - 68)
    topRight = (topLeft[0] + SHAPE_WIDTH * 2, topLeft[1])
    bottomLeft = (topLeft[0], topLeft[1] + SHAPE_HEIGHT)
    bottomRight = (topRight[0], topRight[1] + SHAPE_HEIGHT)
    pygame.draw.lines(self.display, WHITE, True,
            [topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft], 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Game().play()
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are asking for is a way to more easily specify at which rareshapecount intervals you should place a rare shape instead of a normal shape, the following approach is more readable:

```
def randomize(self):
   """
   Replace the entire board with fresh shapes.
   """
   # locations we want to place a rare shape
   rare_shapes = [9, 23, 27]

   for i in range(self.size):
      if i in rare_shapes:
         self.board[i] = Cell(random.choice(self.rareshapes))
      else:
         self.board[i] = Cell (random.choice(self.shapes))
```

Optionally, you could randomly populate rare_shapes if you don't feel like hardcoding the intervals each time, making for a more varied experience (i.e., if you're designing a game or something similar).

Comment: This was an awesome change!  Can't believe I didn't think about this myself.  However, its still not what I need.  Rather than (random.choice(self.rareshapes)), I would like to be able to PICK which rareshape goes in each spot.  So, when it hits 9, I want the reda.png image to appear.  When it hits 23, maybe I want the blueu.png to appear in that spot.  For the puzzle game we are trying to work on, we need to be able to pick what rareshapes appear in each spot.  The (random.choice(self.shapes)) can always be random because those are just "filler" shapes.  Hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by "I can decide what rareshape spawns instead of it picking a random rareshape" is unclear to me. Would you care to give more explanations ? Like how you would tell the program which rareshape to use ?

In the meantime, here's a somewhat more pythonic version of your code:

```
def randomize(self):
    """
    Replace the entire board with fresh shapes.
    """

    specials = dict((x, self.rareshapes) for x in (9, 23, 27))
    get_shape_source = lambda x: specials.get(x, self.shapes) 

    for i in xrange(min(self.size, 41)):
        self.board[i] = Cell(random.choice(get_shape_source(i)))
```

Note that this would break if `len(self.board) < min(self.size, 41)` but well, that's still basically what your current code do.

edit: given your comment, the obvious way to explicitly choose which rareshape goes where is to explicitly associate images with spots. Now what's the best way to do so / the best place ton configure this really depends on your whole code or at least on more than what you posted. As a very simple and minimal exemple, you could just have this:

```
from collections import ordereddict

def load_images(self)  
    self.image_color = {}
    self.shapes = []
    self.rareshapes = ordereddict()

    colors = 'red',  'blue', 'yellow'
    letters = 'acgtu'

    for c in colors:
        im = pygame.image.load('images/{}.png'.format(c))
        self.shapes.append(im)
        self.image_color[im] = c
        for l in letters:
            im = pygame.image.load('rareimages/{}{}.png'.format(c, l))
            self.rareshapes.[(c, l)] = im
            self.image_color[im] = l

def randomize(self):
    """
    Replace the entire board with fresh shapes.
    """

    raremap = {
       # spot index : rareshape
       9: ('red', 'a')],  
       23: ('blue', 'u'), 
       27: ('yellow', 'g') 
       }

    for i in xrange(self.size):
        if i in raremap:
            im = self.rareshapes[raremap[i]]
        else:
            im = random.choice(self.shapes)
        self.board[i] = Cell(im)
```

But it will be just unmaintainable in the long run - too much hardcoded stuff, and too much knowledge leaking from one method to another. I don't know what 'self' is an instance of, but you should considered splitting the responsabilities so you have the invariant parts in one class and the "configration" (images to load, spots / rareshapes mapping etc) in another. Some design patterns that come to mind are TemplateMethod (where you have an abstract base class with the invariant parts and concrete subclasses implementing the "configuration" part), Builder, and of course Strategy (in your case the "Strategy" class would take care of the configuration).

Comment: Check out the comment above for hopefully a better idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I tried adding what you posted above with no luck.  I am going to edit the post above with the full code so you can take a look at everything.  The game is not going to be anything huge and most likely well never be released so its doesn't need to be all that maintainable.  The method you posted looks good and is easy to understand, but my lack of python and programming knowledge is holding me back.  Working on these types of programs really helps when I can see a working a program and then going over all the code to see what makes it all work.